# Per-directory local settings in Dired, to sort folders differently

Tags: dired

I was wondering if one can have a set of definitions in dired to sort (and maybe also filter) that are per directory. this would be also saved for all future sessions.
any one knows of such a method?

Answer (score 1):

There's a MELPA package for that:

https://gitlab.com/xuhdev/dired-quick-sort#dired-quick-sort

Comment: Hi. this package only sorts the buffer your in. as far as i can tell it dosent remember sort position for every buffer between sessions? also i would like filtering, exclusion etc remembered.

Comment: From lines 29-30 of the code:

;; With `savehist-mode' enabled (strongly recommended), the last used sorting
;; criteria are automatically used when sorting, even after restarting Emacs.